# Replace Text on Hover with Jquery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way with Jquery or JS to make it so that when I mouseover one of these divs, the text and icon disappears and "Read More" appears. I've seen some guides but they don't really seem to be accomplishing the whole job, it removes one line of text rather than clearing the entire div, and replacing it with a centered "Read More" text on mouseover, then going back to the normal text when the mouse exits hover. Does anyone have any suggestions?
The divs are horizontal on the actual page, not sure why it's showing up as vertical here.

```css
.feature-container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.feature-box {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.feature-box i {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature-box:hover {
  background: #208541 !important;
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

.feature-box.dark {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-container">


  <div class="feature-box-container feature-slider">
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
      <h4>Content</h4>
      <p>Effective learning methodology that focuses on concepts and understanding of AICPA blueprints.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>
      <h4>Customization</h4>
      <p>Adaptive content for a custom learning experience and individualized delivery through AdaptaPASS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-help"></i>
      <h4>Support</h4>
      <p>Direct access to our instructors and CPAs, by phone, email, or via our student-only message board.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-social-usd-outline"></i>
      <h4>Value</h4>
      <p>Everything you need -- for less. Our course bundle costs hundreds less than competitors.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your JS too please?

Comment: Also if you can put your code into jsfiddle/jsbin/codepen that would be useful for us, thanks

Comment: What's wrong with a StackOverflow snippet @MattFletcher?

Comment: It just further helps to be able to see the issue in an actual functioning environment for a visual question, rather than reading minified CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you to get started.. I'm using `.css('visibility', 'hidden');` to hide text only because I didn't wanted to change or alter box height..
Ofcourse if that is not the case that you need (you can only use some css to fix the height) then you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` to show and hide text on mouse events

```js
$('.feature-box').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).find('i, h4:not(.rm), p').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $(this).find('h4.rm').css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('.feature-box').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).find('i, h4:not(.rm), p').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $(this).find('h4.rm').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.feature-container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
h4.rm{ visibility: hidden; }
.feature-box {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.feature-box i {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature-box:hover {
  background: #208541 !important;
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

.feature-box.dark {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature-container">


  <div class="feature-box-container feature-slider">
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
      <h4>Content</h4>
      <h4 class="rm">Read more</h4>
      <p>Effective learning methodology that focuses on concepts and understanding of AICPA blueprints.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>
      <h4>Customization</h4>
      <h4 class="rm">Read more</h4>
      <p>Adaptive content for a custom learning experience and individualized delivery through AdaptaPASS.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-help"></i>
      <h4>Support</h4>
      <h4 class="rm">Read more</h4>
      <p>Direct access to our instructors and CPAs, by phone, email, or via our student-only message board.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-social-usd-outline"></i>
      <h4>Value</h4>
      <h4 class="rm">Read more</h4>
      <p>Everything you need -- for less. Our course bundle costs hundreds less than competitors.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I suggest you to use CSS only solution.

Add new div, position it `absolutely` and on feature-box hover just display it.

In order the position to work, feature-box has to have `position: relative` and new div should have larger `z-index`, and `top: 0;` set

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `css` see below if that is what you require.

```css
.feature-container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.feature-box {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.read-more {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}

.feature-box:hover p {
  display: none;
}

.feature-box:hover span.read-more {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.feature-box i {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature-box:hover {
  background: #208541 !important;
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

.feature-box.dark {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature-container">


  <div class="feature-box-container feature-slider">
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
      <h4>Content</h4>
      <p>Effective learning methodology that focuses on concepts and understanding of AICPA blueprints.</p><span class="read-more">read more</span>

    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>
      <h4>Customization</h4>
      <p>Adaptive content for a custom learning experience and individualized delivery through AdaptaPASS.</p><span class="read-more">read more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">
      <i class="ion-help"></i>
      <h4>Support</h4>
      <p>Direct access to our instructors and CPAs, by phone, email, or via our student-only message board.</p><span class="read-more">read more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box dark">
      <i class="ion-social-usd-outline"></i>
      <h4>Value</h4>
      <p>Everything you need -- for less. Our course bundle costs hundreds less than competitors.</p>
      <span class="read-more">read more</span>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to dynamically manipulate de 'boxes', you could do it using a couple of extra tag and css like this:

```css
.feature-container{ box-shadow:0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); position:relative; z-index:9;  width:100%; display:inline-block;}
.feature-box{background:#fff; text-align:center; padding:40px 30px; position:relative; width:25%;display:inline-block;}
.feature-box i{font-size:50px; margin-bottom:15px; cursor:pointer;}
.feature-box:hover{background:#208541 !important; color:#f6f6f6;}
.feature-box.dark{background:#f6f6f6;}

.feature-box .mask{display:none;}
.feature-box:hover .mask{background-color:#333;color:white;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;margin:auto;text-align:center;display:block;}
.feature-box:hover .mask span{position: relative;float: left;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
```

```html
<div class="feature-container" >


  <div class="feature-box-container feature-slider">
         <div class="feature-box">
             <i class="ion-ios-list-outline"></i>
                    <h4>Content</h4>
                    <p>Effective learning methodology that focuses on concepts and understanding of AICPA blueprints.</p>
                    <a class="mask" href="#"><span>read more</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box dark">
             <i class="ion-ios-cog-outline"></i>
                    <h4>Customization</h4>
                    <p>Adaptive content for a custom learning experience and individualized delivery through AdaptaPASS.</p>
                    <a class="mask" href="#"><span>read more</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box">
             <i class="ion-help"></i>
                    <h4>Support</h4>
                    <p>Direct access to our instructors and CPAs, by phone, email, or via our student-only message board.</p>
                    <a class="mask" href="#"><span>read more</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box dark">
             <i class="ion-social-usd-outline"></i>
                    <h4>Value</h4>
                    <p>Everything you need -- for less. Our course bundle costs hundreds less than competitors.</p>
                    <a class="mask" href="#"><span>read more</span></a>
            </div>
         </div>


  </div>
```

if you dont need any fancy styles for the "read more" text, you could use `.feature-box:hover::before{}` to add the text and center it as i did with `.mask span`.